# Why do api's have to be different for every darn browser?

Tags: api, browser

Like RTCPeerConnection for example. The api for this is different in firefox, chrome.

This code snippet is just to fix the differences for that api. It demosntrates the annoyance developers face trying to create sites that work in all main modern browsers:...
I am really grateful to whoever created this. It's a great fix.

```
var RTCPeerConnection = null;
var getUserMedia = null;
var attachMediaStream = null;
var reattachMediaStream = null;
var webrtcDetectedBrowser = null;
function trace(text) {
    if (text[text.length - 1] == '\\') {
        text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    }
    console.log((performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ": " + text);
}

if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
    console.log("This appears to be Firefox");
    webrtcDetectedBrowser = "firefox";

    RTCPeerConnection = mozRTCPeerConnection;
    RTCSessionDescription = mozRTCSessionDescription;
    RTCIceCandidate = mozRTCIceCandidate;
    getUserMedia = navigator.mozGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);
    attachMediaStream = function (element, stream) {
        console.log("Attaching media stream");
        element.mozSrcObject = stream;
        element.play();
    };
    reattachMediaStream = function (to, from) {
        console.log("Reattaching media stream");
        to.mozSrcObject = from.mozSrcObject;
        to.play();
    };
    MediaStream.prototype.getVideoTracks = function () {
        return [];
    };
    MediaStream.prototype.getAudioTracks = function () {
        return [];
    };
} else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) {
    console.log("This appears to be Chrome");
    webrtcDetectedBrowser = "chrome";
    RTCPeerConnection = webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia.bind(navigator);

    attachMediaStream = function (element, stream) {
        if (typeof element.srcObject !== 'undefined') {
            element.srcObject = stream;
        } else
        {
            if (typeof element.mozSrcObject !== 'undefined') {
                element.mozSrcObject = stream;
            } else
            {
                if (typeof element.src !== 'undefined') {
                    element.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                } else {
                    console.log('Error attaching stream to element.');
                }
            }
        }
    };
    reattachMediaStream = function (to, from) {
        to.src = from.src;
    };
    if (!webkitMediaStream.prototype.getVideoTracks) {
        webkitMediaStream.prototype.getVideoTracks = function () {
            return this.videoTracks;
        };
        webkitMediaStream.prototype.getAudioTracks = function () {
            return this.audioTracks;
        };
    }
    if (!webkitRTCPeerConnection.prototype.getLocalStreams) {
        webkitRTCPeerConnection.prototype.getLocalStreams = function () {
            return this.localStreams;
        };
        webkitRTCPeerConnection.prototype.getRemoteStreams = function () {
            return this.remoteStreams;
        };
    }
} else {
    console.log("Browser does not appear to be WebRTC-capable");
}
```

Why do the creators of these web browsers have to be so awkward? I cant really understand it lol?

Answer (score 0):

This is summed up in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection)

> This is an experimental technology
>
> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.

Or [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/):

> Publication as an Editor's Draft does not imply endorsement by the W3C Membership. This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.

In short: You are living on the bleeding edge and implementing specifications which are still being designed. Finished specifications tend to get stable, consistent implementations across browsers.

Comment: that's fair enough dude. I guess websocket is almost stable now. I like all these new specifications. They are great for things like chat sites!

Answer (score 0):

The WebRTC specification has changed a lot in recent years and some browsers still don't support it enough to unprefix their versions of the PeerConnection or getUserMedia APIs (Mozilla recently has).

The snippet you have is from a project called [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter). You might want to use that version instead of your outdated one.